# how to offset results when retrieving data from freebase

Tags: metadata, freebase

is there a way to offset results when retrieving data from a query like below? is there a property like "limit: x, but just for offsetting (besides "&cursor=")?

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?
query[{"type":"/cvg/computer_videogame",...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the cursor is your only option.  Alternatively, you can make your query more specific to do the offsetting at the query level (e.g. query a smaller time range, etc).

Comment: Understood, but how come I get a timeout if i do a for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++), using the new cursor from each result, with limit set to 100?

Comment: The two most likely reasons are: 1) your query is too hard, 2) Google's back end is having problems.  If it's #1 and you're close to the edge, you may find that reducing the limit helps (you're going to be paging through them anyway, so that really only affects the amount of overhead).